# Can BLE devices act as beacons

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

This could be a wrong question but just need to know whether this is feasible 
For one of our ble devices the manufcaturer data comes as when scanned using the noble package using the [`peripheral.advertisement.manufacturerData`]

`manufacturerData: <Buffer 59 00 08 8a 00 00 50 f8 c8 f0 6e b9 cd> }`.This data mainly has some data related to the device like the battery level and hardware versions. 
Can this device work as a beacon as well as a ble device if we change the advertising package ?

Comment: Yes. But you have change payload periodically.

Comment: Does that mean every alternate advertisement has to be of ble device and beacon.means if currently every 200ms we push the advertisement data then we can make it like at 100ms interval it push the ad data for ble device and another 100ms interval it can push ble beacon data ?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this is all possible. I have built exactly this capability into many IoT projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, any BLE device can act as a beacon as long as you can control the advertisement payload. Beacons are a subset of BLE devices. By definition, beacons are BLE devices that are constantly/continuously advertising data that are relevant to other remote devices, usually containing information about its location/proximity.

So to answer your question, as Mike Petrichenko suggested, all you need to do is alter your advertisement data to something that is relevant to remote devices. If you still need to send your current adverts, then you'll need to alternate between sending the current advert data and the relevant beacon data. You can control the frequency at which each data is sent depending on your application (e.g. For every 10 adverts of your current payload you can send the beacon advert if it's less frequently needed).

Some references:-

[What Are Beacons and How Beacons Technology Works](https://www.intellectsoft.net/blog/what-are-beacons-and-how-do-they-work/)

[5 Things You Need to Know about Beacon Technology](https://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2018/10/04/beacon-technology)

[What Are Beacons, and How Are They Used in IoT Applications](https://dataconomy.com/2018/03/what-are-beacons-and-how-are-they-used-in-iot-projects/)

I hope this helps.